# Dynamic file access control

Tags: linux, files, access-control

I have a shared folder that different program use.
I would like to be able for "file events" in this folder, like file creation, access for read or write.
The idea is to hang the open of the file until another program (and eventually a user) will give permission  to proceed.
This solution can be specific to linux

Comment: You probably have to write your own FUSE file system for that.

Comment: [Fanotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fanotify_init.2.html) may help. Look at the `FAN_CLASS_PRE_CONTENT` class.